# Extjs Dynamically wrapping items in a container

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Why is this so difficult? I've got a container, layout:'hbox', and a collection of buttons in it. The problem is that the buttons continue beyond the right bounds of the container. What are the best practice methods of wrapping content inside of a container? Should I just float:"left" my child items? I can use fixed widths everywhere, my site does not resize horizontally.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The proper way to do what I was looking for here was to use `layout:'column'` which would treat its children like floating divs.

Comment: This was extremely helpful for my configuration as well where I use a vbox layout with items in a container. Setting the container to a column layout allowed for the wrapping I needed.

Comment: I've spent hours looking for this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

hbox layout is not the proper layout if you want content to overflow into the next 'row'. Hbox aligns and distributes components across a fixed width in a single row.
Better stick with 'auto' layout (which is the default) and allow the browser to control the overflow via CSS float (just as you mentioned).

Alternatively, you could use `Ext.toolbar.Toolbar#enableOverflow` - see the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-cfg-enableOverflow)

> Configure true to make the toolbar provide a button which activates a dropdown Menu to show items which overflow the Toolbar's width.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to help; I left `layout` by default as `auto` and used additional CSS to achieve `wrap` approach within `responsive` usage;

Some nested-children containers are rendering into `foocontainer` dynamically. So totally having responsive UI within CSS.

```
.foocontainer > div[data-ref="outerCt"] > div[data-ref="innerCt"] {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex!important;
  flex-wrap: wrap!important;
}
```